# Call to a member function manages() on null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

resources / views / layouts / navigation.blade .php : 8 require

in my home page  Laravel

```
<!-- resources/views/page.blade.php -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Front Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Include the navigation menu -->
        @include('layouts.navigation')

        <!-- Your front page content goes here -->
        <h1>Welcome to the front page</h1>
        <p>This is the content of your front page.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my layout navigation

i have error in this line : @if (auth()->user()->manages())

Call to a member function manages() on null

Expand vendor frames resources / views / layouts / navigation.blade .php : 8 require 9 vendor frames resources / views / welcome.blade .php : 10 require 56 vendor frames public / index .php : 51 require_once 1 vendor frame

Comment: If you're not logged in, `auth()->user()` will be null. You may want to look at the `@auth` and `@guest` blade directives for only running certain code if you are or are not logged in. https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#authentication-directives

Comment: `@if (auth()->user()->manages()){}@endif` basically auth is use for `authentication` when user login then it will work otherwise it's empty/null.so before use this condition you must login or you may use this
`@if (auth()->user() != null)
{
 @if (auth()->user()->manages())
 {
 }
@endif
}@endif`

Or use **ternary operator**
`{{ (auth()->user() != null && auth()->user()->manages()) ? 'Manager' : '' }}`

Comment: thanks patricus and Muhammad Umair

Comment: it's my pleasure @Mario

Comment: When posting a question and code, make sure that you post the code that causes your issue. As you mentioned yourself, the layout you've posted isn't where the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

That means, you dont have an authenticated user, so check first if `auth()->user()` exists, like:

```
  @if (!is_null(auth()->user())) //if auth()->user() is not null, you can call the manages() function on it
     @if(auth()->user()->manages())
       //content you want
     @endif
  @endif
```

Comment: `auth()->check()` returns a boolean btw

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [optional](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-optional) helper from laravel.

It allows you to call methods or access properties off of objects, if the object is `null`, instead of throwing an error, `null` is returned ie;

```php
@if (optional(auth()->user())->manages())

// your template stuff

@endif
```